# Flask 405 error even though I've put Get in methods

Tags: python, flask, routes, jinja2

I'm building a simple flask app. It accepts numbers from a form, calculates a value from these and then gives it back to the user. I am struggling with an error which keeps popping up saying that 'The method is not allowed for the requested URL.' I (think) ive correctly included the get and post methods for this so im not sure why im getting this error. The app has a wsgi.py type set up. Code is below:

In routes.py:

```
@app.route('/extraplace/advancedcalculator', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def calculator():
    form = Extraplacecalculatorform()
    chanceep = 1.555
    investmentreturn= 1.555
    if request.method == 'POST':
        back_odds = form.back_odds.data
        ran = form.Number_running.data
        chanceep = calculate_chanceep(back_odds, ran)
        investmentreturn = (chanceep * form.back_odds.data)
    return render_template('completedcalculator.jinja2', chanceep=chanceep, form=form, investmentreturn=investmentreturn)
```

In completedcalculator.jinja2:

```
{% block body %}
<h1>Input your information</h1> 

<div class="formwrapper">
  <h2 class="title">Contact</h2>
    <form method="POST" action="/">
        <div class="form-back_odds">{{ form.back_odds.label }} {{ form.back_odds(size=20) }}</div>
        <div class="form-lay_odds">{{ form.lay_odds.label }} {{ form.lay_odds }}</div>
        <div class="form-extraplace_payout">{{ form.extraplace_payout.label }} {{ form.extraplace_payout }}</div>
        <div class="form-Number_running">{{ form.Number_running.label }} {{ form.Number_running }}</div>
      <div class="submit-button"> {{ form.submit }}</div>
  </form>
</div>

<br>
<br>

{% if chanceep == 1.555 %}
<div>
<a class="btn btn-success" role="button">From analysis of over 10,000 horse races in the past 10 years. Our model predicts a {{chanceep}}% chance that the horse will finish in the extraplace meaning that you will have a {{investmentreturn}}% return of investment&raquo;</a>
</div>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

The idea behind the code is that by declaring the values of chanceep every time the page is accessed, the value of chanceep could be 1.555 if it is a get request, or the new calculated value if it is a post request. Then in the Jinja file, it will only show the bottom button with details of the calculations if the value is not 1.555 (it is currently only showing if it is 1.555 however for simplicity).

I am able to access the page for the first time however I get the error as soon as I try to post. If anyone has any ideas why this might be I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You're setting `action="/"` in the form, which is not the same route `/extraplace/advancedcalculator` you defined for the function.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:

I solved this issue by changing the code within the formwrapper from:

```
<div class="formwrapper">
      <h2 class="title">Contact</h2>
        <form method="POST" action="/">
            <div class="form-back_odds">{{ form.back_odds.label }} {{ form.back_odds(size=20) }}</div>
```

to:

```
    <div class="formwrapper">
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <div class="form-back_odds">{{ form.back_odds.label }} {{ form.back_odds(size=20) }}</div>
```